# How to plot and work with NaN values in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have hourly data consisting of a number of columns. First column is a date (`date_log`), and the rest of columns contain different sample points. The trouble is sample points are logged using different time even on hourly basis, so every column has at least a couple of `NaN`. If I plot up using the first code it works nicely, but I want to have gaps where there no logger data for a day or so and do not want the points to be joined. If I use the second code I can see the gaps but due to NaN points the data points are not getting joined. In the example below, I’m just plotting the first three columns.

When there is a big gap like the blue points (01/06-01/07/2015) I want to have a gap then the points getting joined. The second example does not join the points. I like the first chart but I want to create gaps like the second method when there are no sample data points for 24h date range etc. leaving missing data points for longer times as a gap.

Is there any work around? Thanks

**Method-1**:

```
Log_1a_mask = np.isfinite(Log_1a) # Log_1a is column 2 data points
Log_1b_mask = np.isfinite(Log_1b) # Log_1b is column 3 data points

plt.plot_date(date_log[Log_1a_mask], Log_1a[Log_1a_mask], linestyle='-', marker='',color='r',)
plt.plot_date(date_log[Log_1b_mask], Log_1b[Log_1b_mask], linestyle='-', marker='', color='b')
plt.show()
```

**Method-2**:

```
plt.plot_date(date_log, Log_1a, ‘-r*’, markersize=2, markeredgewidth=0, color=’r’) # Log_1a contains raw data with NaN
plt.plot_date(date_log, Log_1b, ‘-r*’, markersize=2, markeredgewidth=0, color=’r’) # Log_1a contains raw data with NaN
plt.show()
```

Method-1 output:
[image]

Method-2 output:
[image]

Comment: Can you please describe exactly what you want? I understand both your examples, but I am unsure of what aspect you precisely want for your graph.

Comment: when there is a big gap like the blue points (01/06-01/07/2015) I want to have a gap then the points to get joined. The second example does not join the points. I really want to use the first method, but want to avoid big data gaps, say like 24 hour gap etc.

Comment: In other words, you want the measurements to appear continuous if they are at a shorter interval than a maximum (tbd), otherwise, you want to have a gap between the series. Have I understood well?

Comment: That's exactly what I want!

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly, you have a dataset with lots of small gaps (single `NaN`s) that you want filled and larger gaps that you don't.

### Using `pandas` to "forward-fill" gaps

One option is to use `pandas` `fillna` with a limited amount of fill values.

As a quick example of how this works:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd; import numpy as np

In [2]: x = pd.Series([1, np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 3, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 4])

In [3]: x.fillna(method='ffill', limit=1)
Out[3]:
0     1
1     1
2     2
3     2
4   NaN
5     3
6     3
7   NaN
8   NaN
9     4
dtype: float64

In [4]: x.fillna(method='ffill', limit=2)
Out[4]:
0     1
1     1
2     2
3     2
4     2
5     3
6     3
7     3
8   NaN
9     4
dtype: float64
```

As an example of using this for something similar to your case:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(1977)

x = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000).cumsum()

# Set every third value to NaN
x[::3] = np.nan

# Set a few bigger gaps...
x[20:100], x[200:300], x[400:450] = np.nan, np.nan, np.nan

# Use pandas with a limited forward fill
# You may want to adjust the `limit` here. This will fill 2 nan gaps.
filled = pd.Series(x).fillna(limit=2, method='ffill')

# Let's plot the results
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)
axes[0].plot(x, color='lightblue')
axes[1].plot(filled, color='lightblue')

axes[0].set(ylabel='Original Data')
axes[1].set(ylabel='Filled Data')

plt.show()
```

[image]

### Using `numpy` to interpolate gaps

Alternatively, we can do this using only `numpy`.  It's possible (and more efficient) to do a "forward fill" identical to the pandas method above, but I'll show another method to give you more options than just repeating values.

Instead of repeating the last value through the "gap", we can perform linear interpolation of the values in the gap.  This is less efficient computationally (and I'm going to make it even less efficient by interpolating everywhere), but for most datasets you won't notice a major difference.

As an example, let's define an `interpolate_gaps` function:

```
def interpolate_gaps(values, limit=None):
    """
    Fill gaps using linear interpolation, optionally only fill gaps up to a
    size of `limit`.
    """
    values = np.asarray(values)
    i = np.arange(values.size)
    valid = np.isfinite(values)
    filled = np.interp(i, i[valid], values[valid])

    if limit is not None:
        invalid = ~valid
        for n in range(1, limit+1):
            invalid[:-n] &= invalid[n:]
        filled[invalid] = np.nan

    return filled
```

Note that we'll get interpolated value, unlike the previous `pandas` version:

```
In [11]: values = [1, np.nan, 2, np.nan, np.nan, 3, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 4]

In [12]: interpolate_gaps(values, limit=1)
Out[12]:
array([ 1.        ,  1.5       ,  2.        ,         nan,  2.66666667,
        3.        ,         nan,         nan,  3.75      ,  4.        ])
```

In the plotting example, if we replace the line:

```
filled = pd.Series(x).fillna(limit=2, method='ffill')
```

With:

```
filled = interpolate_gaps(x, limit=2)
```

We'll get a visually identical plot:

[image]

As a complete, stand-alone example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(1977)

def interpolate_gaps(values, limit=None):
    """
    Fill gaps using linear interpolation, optionally only fill gaps up to a
    size of `limit`.
    """
    values = np.asarray(values)
    i = np.arange(values.size)
    valid = np.isfinite(values)
    filled = np.interp(i, i[valid], values[valid])

    if limit is not None:
        invalid = ~valid
        for n in range(1, limit+1):
            invalid[:-n] &= invalid[n:]
        filled[invalid] = np.nan

    return filled

x = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000).cumsum()

# Set every third value to NaN
x[::3] = np.nan

# Set a few bigger gaps...
x[20:100], x[200:300], x[400:450] = np.nan, np.nan, np.nan

# Interpolate small gaps using numpy
filled = interpolate_gaps(x, limit=2)

# Let's plot the results
fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)
axes[0].plot(x, color='lightblue')
axes[1].plot(filled, color='lightblue')

axes[0].set(ylabel='Original Data')
axes[1].set(ylabel='Filled Data')

plt.show()
```

Note: I originally completely mis-read the question. See version history for my original answer.

Comment: In my data every sample point has NaN after each real data, e.g. [1, nan, 2, nan, nan, nan, 3, nan, nan, 4, nan] - so if you don't avoid nan then no points get joined. You have basically re-written the second method which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: @Kudrat - Ah! Sorry, I didn't read your question closely enough. In that case, you can use a limited forward fill.  `pandas` has it built-in (`series.fillna(limit=2)`), but you could also implement one in a few lines of numpy.  I'll add an example in a bit.  Also, my apologies for not reading your question closely. It was perfectly clear, but I wasn't paying enough attention.

Comment: Yes not to worry, that would be great if you could just include your example whenever convenient..Cheers

Comment: any suggestions please?

Comment: @Kudrat - Sorry for my delay - Got caught up in other things.  See the updated answer above. Hope that helps!

Comment: Wow what a complete and comprehensive answer! Thanks a lot! I was after the first option, but good to know the ability of interpolation which might come handy

Comment: Is there a way to fill in the gaps without changing the data series?  changing the series means there will be a dot for each point with `style='.-'` even if it's not in the original data

Comment: @endolith, i know your comment is old and this question is older, but you could try plotting twice: `plt.plot()` with `linestyle = "-"` for a copy of the data series with forward fill/interpolation. Then `plt.plot()` with only markers and no lines for the true data. Of course, then you'd have to fiddle some more to get any legends to work right (e.g., make a dummy entry) but, to me, this seems simplest.

Answer (score 0):

I simply use this function:

```
import math
for i in range(1,len(data)):
  if math.isnan(data[i]):
    data[i] = data[i-1]
```