# How can I forward fill -9999 values in python?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas dataframe which I need to plot by ignoring the -9999 values. If I use `ylim`, it creates drops like in this question ([Working with NaN values in matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36455083/working-with-nan-values-in-matplotlib))

I know this can be used to forward fill NAN values:

```
fillna(method='ffill', limit=1)
```

But, I have -9999 values that need to be filled.

How to do this?

Comment: I do not understand your question. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have a pandas dataframe with -9999 values that I want to fill with the previous value in the sequence...

Comment: That is not a [mcve]

Comment: you mean `df.loc[df['variable'] == -9999, 'variable'] = np.nan` ?

Comment: @maximusdooku sounds like you're really asking how to replace a particular value with `numpy.nan`

Comment: @LucasDresl Thank you! That's what I was looking for. I wasn't sure how to frame the question..

Comment: @maximusdooku ur welcome, i post the answer so u can upvote and check it as correct :)!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you mean `df.loc[df['variable'] == -9999, 'variable'] = np.nan` ?

Answer (score 1):

Sound like this is what you're looking for:

```
# Replace all -9999s with NaNs to make it easier to work with
df.replace(to_replace=-9999, value=np.nan, inplace=True)

# forward fill those values
fillna(method='ffill', limit=1)
```

Update for your question revision:

Without seeing the data, and based on your desire to graph the series, panda's [Series.interpolate's methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) might be more useful for filling than ffill.

Answer (score 1):

Let' use `mask` and `ffill`:

```
df.mask(df.eq(-9999)).ffill(limit=1)
```